# Faster way to summarise variables based on column

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I wish to summarise some variables in my data frame based on a column. However my data frame is rather large (>30,000,000 rows) and using the summarise function in dplyr takes ages to run. Is there a faster way in R to speed up the summarising process?

I have a data frame df in the format:

```
  proid  X1  X2  X3 X4
1     1  zz   a   e  a
2     2  ff   g   z  b
3     1  cd   s   f  d 
4     3  ab   t   e  e
5     2  ta   b   h  k
      ....
```

I wish to concatenate the variables X1 to X4 when they have the same prodid value. The concatenated strings are separated by commas. So the above table should give me the new table:

```
  proid     X1   X2   X3  X4
1     1  zz,cd  a,s  e,f a,d 
2     2  ff,ta  g,b  z,h b,k
3     3     ab    t    e   e
      ....
```

I have used the following dplyr code:

```
concat <- function(x){
  x <- na.omit(x)
  if(length(x)==0){
    return(as.character(NA))
  }else{
    return(paste(x,collapse=","))
  }
}

dg<-group_by(df,proid)
df<-summarise(dg,proid,concat(X1),concat(X2),concat(X3),concat(X4))
```

Comment: try `setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, concat), by = proid]` and see what the timings look like

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Edit note:** removed original part of my answer that didn't address NA treatment & added a benchmark.

```
concat2 <- function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA_character_ else paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ",")
```

Using data.table:

```
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, concat2), by = proid, .SDcols = -c("X4")]
#   proid    X1  X2  X3
#1:     1 zz,cd a,s e,f
#2:     2 ff,ta g,b z,h
#3:     3    NA   t   e
```

Using dplyr:

```
df %>% group_by(proid) %>% summarise_each(funs(concat2), -X4)
```

**Benchmark**, smaller data than in actual use case and not fully representative, so just wanted to get an impression how `concat2` compares to `concat` etc..

```
library(microbenchmark)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

N <- 1e6
x <- c(letters, LETTERS)
df <- data.frame(
  proid = sample(1e4, N, TRUE),
  X1 = sample(sample(c(x, NA), N, TRUE)),
  X2 = sample(sample(c(x, NA), N, TRUE)),
  X3 = sample(sample(c(x, NA), N, TRUE)),
  X4 = sample(sample(c(x, NA), N, TRUE))
  )

dt <- as.data.table(df)

concat <- function(x){
  x <- na.omit(x)
  if(length(x)==0){
    return(as.character(NA))
  }else{
    return(paste(x,collapse=","))
  }
}

concat2 <- function(x) if(all(is.na(x))) NA_character_ else paste(na.omit(x), collapse = ",")

concat.dplyr <- function(){
  df %>% group_by(proid) %>% summarise_each(funs(concat), -X4)
}

concat2.dplyr <- function(){
  df %>% group_by(proid) %>% summarise_each(funs(concat2), -X4)
}

concat.data.table <- function(){
  dt[, lapply(.SD, concat), by = proid, .SDcols = -c("X4")]
}

concat2.data.table <- function(){
  dt[, lapply(.SD, concat2), by = proid, .SDcols = -c("X4")]
}


microbenchmark(concat.dplyr(), 
               concat2.dplyr(), 
               concat.data.table(), 
               concat2.data.table(),
               unit = "relative",
               times = 10L)
Unit: relative
                 expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
       concat.dplyr() 1.058839 1.058342 1.083728 1.105907 1.080883    10
      concat2.dplyr() 1.057991 1.065566 1.109099 1.145657 1.079201    10
  concat.data.table() 1.024101 1.018443 1.093604 1.085254 1.066560    10
 concat2.data.table() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10
```

Findings: data.table performs a little bit faster than dplyr on the sample data and `concat2` is a little faster than `concat`. However, differences remain rather small on this sample data set.

Comment: The data.table version runs in about one-fourth the time of the dplyr version on my computer. The dplyr/tidyr version by @StevenBeaupre runs in about 1.5 times the dplyr version.

Comment: Neither of these solutions account for `na.omit()` in OP's function though... @eipi10, the speed difference with `dplyr` would be largely dependent on a) number of groups, and b) the number of rows (in that order)...

Comment: @user22119, probably you should get familiar then :P. Start with the HTML vignettes [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started).

Comment: Woops, accidentally deleted my previous comment. Just like to find out for the data table version, is it possible to limit the aggregation to X1 to X3 and leave out X4?

Comment: Good point, @Arun, overlooked that part initially. eddi's comment looks promising

Comment: No reason to keep the part of the answer that doesn't address `NA`, eh? Also, you might want to add a line showing the modification to the example that leads to an `NA` in your result, `df[4,"X1"] <- NA` maybe? Finally, what's wrong with the OP's `concat` function? Seems fine to me, and doesn't have the redundancy of `is.na` and `na.omit` in `concat2`.

Answer (score 2):

`na.omit` does a ton of unnecessary checks and operations. Replacing it with simple `is.na` call will give you a decent speedup:

```
concat3 = function(x) {
  x = x[!is.na(x)]
  if (length(x) == 0)
    NA_character_
  else
    paste(x, collapse = ",")
}
```

Using docendo's data (but with strings instead of factors - factors slow all versions down):

```
microbenchmark(dt[, lapply(.SD, concat3), by = proid, .SDcols = -c("X4")],
               dt[, lapply(.SD, concat2), by = proid, .SDcols = -c("X4")],
               times = 5)
#Unit: milliseconds
#                                                       expr       min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# dt[, lapply(.SD, concat3), by = proid, .SDcols = -c("X4")]  960.2475 1079.177 1251.545 1342.684 1402.571 1473.045     5
# dt[, lapply(.SD, concat2), by = proid, .SDcols = -c("X4")] 1718.8121 1892.696 2159.148 2171.772 2470.205 2542.253     5
```